# Empty Cloud Functions params

Tags: ibm-cloud-functions

I'm calling an IBM Cloud Functions web action

```
function main(params) {
    params = JSON.stringify(params)
    return { message: 'params: ' + params };
}
```

using this POST request

```
https://us-south.functions.cloud.ibm.com/api/v1/namespaces/<space>/actions/order?order=123&blocking=true
```

but I don't get the params:

```
"response": {
    "result": {
        "message": "params: {}"
    },
    "status": "success",
    "success": true
},
```

Comment: Aren't parameters in POST sent differently...? Your style is GET.

Comment: yes, they are sent via Postman/POST

Comment: seems to be related to Postman as I can call the web action from Watson Assistant. not sure what I did wrong